# Installing open CV on Mac M1

Tags: opencv, cmake, apple-m1

Im trying to install openCv for the last couple of days on my mac M1, I managed to follow the official documentation from [OpenCv's website](https://opencv.org/opencv-python-for-apples-m1-chip-a-detective-story-with-a-happy-ending/), it works perfectly untill when I try to run this script:

```
cmake -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(pyenv which python3) \
-DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/include/python3.9 \
-DPYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include \
../opencv
```

I encounter this error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/Boogie/OpenCV" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

I don't know how to solve it,
anyone, please help??

Comment: Probably, something wrong in your command line. Please, copy paste it as is into the question post and format as a **code** (e.g. by selecting it and pressing `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button). Blockquote formatting changes representation of characters, so we could miss some of them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your comment, I just did. Could you take a look?

Comment: The last argument to `cmake` (in your command line it is `../opencv`) should refer to the **source directory of OpenCV**. Content of this directory should be similar to [that one](https://github.com/opencv/opencv), as you can see, it contains `CMakeLists.txt`. Where do you have OpenCV sources on your machine?